# How to change the colour of the icons in my navigation bar when hovering over the area, not just the image.

Tags: html, css, image, nav

I'm trying to change the colour of the icons from White to Black in my navigation bar when hovering over the area, not just the image. I've got the image to change when I hover purely over the image, but I would like to expand this to the area around it. Any help would be appreciated, my code is below.

HTML:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}
.navbar a {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2px 0;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.menubar {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">

  <a href="homepage.html">
    <figure>
      <img class="menubar" src="../images/icons/home.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/icons/home_black.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/icons/home.png'" />
      <figcaption>Homepage</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="car.html">
    <figure>
      <img class="menubar" src="../images/icons/car.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/icons/car_black.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/icons/car.png'" />
      <figcaption>Cars</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="motorbike.html">
    <figure>
      <img class="menubar" src="../images/icons/motorcycle.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/icons/motorcycle_black.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/icons/motorcycle.png'" />
      <figcaption>Motorcycles</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="cycle.html">
    <figure>
      <img class="menubar" src="../images/icons/bicycle.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/icons/bicycle_black.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/icons/bicycle.png'" />
      <figcaption>Bicycles</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>

  <a href="boat.html">
    <figure>
      <img class="menubar" src="../images/icons/boat.png" onmouseover="this.src='../images/icons/boat_black.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../images/icons/boat.png'" />
      <figcaption>Boats</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>




</div>
```

Homepage

Cars

Motorcycles

Bicycles

Boats

CSS

Comment: to do what you are attempting you would need alternative images in the other color. You may look at using a font icon library like fontawesome or glyphicons. i recomend that you move your mouseover to css classes possibly use jquery to help

Comment: @happymacarts He does have alternate images in this example. Re-read the question and you'll see he wants to move the JavaScript that swaps out the `img src` to the parent element, so the `a` can be hovered on instead of the `img` to achieve the same effect. To start, I would recommend pulling out the JS so it's no longer inline to accomplish this.

Comment: @JonUleis i missed that he had all the inline js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your current code I came up with several solutions for you.

1. You can move your `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to the `a` tag and use function to change your images.

```js
    function changeImageSrc(target, newSrc) {
      var img = target.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
      img.src = newSrc;
    }
```

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}
.navbar a {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2px 0;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.menubar {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<a href="homepage.html" onmouseover="changeImageSrc(this, '../images/icons/home_black.png')" onmouseout="changeImageSrc(this, '../images/icons/home.png')">
  <figure>
    <img class="menubar" src="../images/icons/home.png" />
    <figcaption>Homepage</figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

It will do, but I don't think it is the best solution.

2. You can achieve the desired result without using javascript at all. Add two images to the `figure` element and show only one at a time using `:hover` css class.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
}
.navbar a {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2px 0;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}
.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.menubar {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
.show-on-hover {
  display: none;
}
.product:hover .hide-on-hover {
  display: none;
}
.product:hover .show-on-hover {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<a class="product" href="motorbike.html">
  <figure>
    <img class="menubar hide-on-hover" title="Hidden on hover" src="../images/icons/motorcycle.png" />
    <img class="menubar show-on-hover" title="Visible on hover" src="../images/icons/motorcycle_black.png" />
    <figcaption>Motorcycles</figcaption>
  </figure>
</a>
```

3. The best solution, imo, would be to use vector icons from font. Then you would be able to change icon color with css. If you have svg's of your icons you can create the font with them using icomoon.io or similar service.

Comment: Would you at all know how best to add a drop down menu to this menu bar?

Comment: @NathanCook, you can try some UI framework, like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) to make UI building process much easier. You can use [Bootstrap navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) component with dropdown, for example.